# Bayesian Network: Independance and Conditional Independance

Tags: artificial-intelligence, probability, bayesian-networks

I'm having some misunderstanding concerning Bayesian network. My main misunderstanding are independence and conditional independence!!

[image]

If e.g. I have to calculate 
`P(Burglary|Johncall)`, 
is it `P(Burglary|Johncalls)=P(Burglary)` because i'm seeing that Burglary is independent of Johncalls??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burglary is independent from JohnCalls **given** Alarm. So P(B|A,J) = P(B|A).

**Explaining the example**

The idea is, that John can only tell you that there is an alarm. But if you already know that there is an alarm, then the phone call from John will tell you nothing new about the possibility of a burglary. Yes, you know that John heard the alarm, but that's not what you're interested in when asking for Burglary.

**Conditional Independence**

In school, you've probably learned about unconditional independence, given when P(A|B) = P(A)*P(B). Unconditional independence makes things easy to calculate but happens pretty rarely - inside the belief network unconditionally independent nodes would be unconnected.

Conditional independence on the other hand is a bit more complicated but happens more often. It means that the probability of two events becomes independent of each other when another "separating" fact is learned.

Comment: does the markov blanket has anything to do with Conditional Independence ??

Comment: @Noor A variable is independent of everything else, given its markov blanket. You don't need to know of anything that is "behind" the blanket. This is similar to markov processes, where the blanket is the last state (t-1), which makes the current state (t) independent of all other past states (< t-1).

Comment: Been a while, sorry for resurrecting this. Is the inverse conclusion valid as well? Is a variable A always dependent of everything *inside* its markov blanket?

Comment: @HendrikWiese Given one node `A`, all other nodes are always a valid Markov Blanket–so the answer is no. But your statement holds for a minimal Markov Blanket, i.e. one where you cannot remove a variable without invalidating the Markov blanket.